# Faster way of solving PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am building a model which, among other things, needs to solve the following PDE multiple times:

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = D_{o} \nabla^2 \phi + s_o - k_o$$

Where $s_o$ and $k_o$ are respectively source and sink grids.

Note that because the equation above represents diffusion of oxygen, which is significantly faster than the biological processes that the model simulates, I could also use the adiabatic solution:

$$D_{o} \nabla^2 \phi + s_o - k_o = 0$$

The equation is to be solved in three dimensions.

I am currently using FiPy (https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy) that uses the Finite Volume Method, which takes about 10 seconds for a 50x50x50 grid with $dx = dy = dz = 1$.

I am not an expert in calculus, but was wondering if the above equation had a direct/one-step solution or if I was limited to numerical methods?

Boundary conditions are no-flux.

Comment: What does $\nabla^3$ mean? Whereas $\nabla^2$, the Laplacian operator, is a scalar operator, $\nabla^3 = \vec{\nabla}\nabla^2$ looks like it should be a vector-valued operator. You mention diffusion, so I'm assuming this is a typo?

Comment: Yes it's increasingly important to write out what dimensions to multiply and which are contractions or outer products the higher exponent for tensor multiplication.

Comment: You're solving 3D diffusion on a fixed Cartesian grid with sources/sinks. What kind of boundary conditions do you have? On the off chance that periodic boundary conditions are allowed, one can numerically solve this problem *very* fast via Fast Fourier Transform techniques, especially if the source/sink term is constant in time.

Comment: @JohnBarber sorry yes, it should be $\nabla^2$. Conditions are no-flux on the boundary. I edited accordingly.

Comment: I would guess you can get similar speeds in Matlab or octave with sparse matrix solvers. Most of the time is building equation system and you only need to do that once. But for really impressive speed I would consider using some software which can use GPU for this as many numerical algorithms are extremely parallellisable and monster GPUs of today have 5000 cores where monster CPUs have maybe 16 or 32 cores.

Comment: You should consider asking this same question here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions. Also, since you are solving the same problem a lot, you should look into reduced order modelling (ROM) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_order_reduction). If you can build a ROM of your problem, it will be fast to solve. However, I am not certain how robust ROMs are with respect to parameter variation, so YMMV.

Comment: @MrD when you say that the FiPy simulation takes 10 seconds, which PDE are you referring to?  The one with $\partial u/\partial t$ or the one without?

Comment: @Kyle the one with

Comment: What time step ($dt$) and final time ($T$) are you using @MrD?

Comment: dt is 1 and T is the default for FiPy which I believe is picked based on some heuristics, but will check

Comment: "so and ko are respectively source and sink grids."  Simple question: do they vary with time and space?

Comment: @rrogers yes, they change each time I have to solve

Comment: Then I presume they are constant for each run.  IMHO you can find analytic solutions (well series with harmonics) for simple boundary conditions using things like separation of variables.  But in real engineering problems, the boundary conditions are too complicated for that to give you anything hints.  You are stuck with some FEA program.   mathreadler above gives a good answer.  Personally I like Comsol for this type of thing but it's pricey, so I don't know how fast it would be.

Comment: Why not pass the problem off to the sales reps for FEA packages: Comsol, Ansys,...   They are usually eager to show off thier products.  They might have tricks that run faster and have time-limited demo versions; alternately they might be willing to do some runs themselves.